# What is a good tutorial series to learn Python for BGE?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I've learned a lot from searching for python related questions as they came up for me, but I still don't feel like I'm getting the overall grasp of python coding. Are there any good resources that you recommended for learning python from the ground up? If so, in what order?

Thank you in advance for your answers and suggestions, 
Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a text based tutorial, for if you learn better from reading tutorials: [CGMasters Python Scripting](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/python-scripting/)
Here is a video based tutorial, for people who like watching tutorials: (See Below)
The video tutorial is a little outdated, but the basic python still applies. I know that the text based tutorial is not a series, but the video one has some more, as it is part one of twenty three. Here is the link to the full playlist: [Blender 2.6 Basic BGE Python Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMYtDzby1wdY3NMM07u9tV0eCJ1HM-llM)

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I read about 3 paragraphs of the text based one and I already feel more knowledgeable in python, haha. Looking forward to going through them :)